# without closing the popup window, how to submit the form value to server

Tags: javascript, jsp

Question: I have one popup window it contains some values in textbox and textarea.
I need to submit the value to server without closing the popup window.

Is there any way....

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Ajax with POST:

```
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

I would also add that you should be able to do a regular POST via form in the popup without closing it anyway. Its just another browser window...