# Go back to dynamic form after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit, field

I've got a form like this:

```html
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="name[]">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<a href="#" id="add">Add field</a>
```

With Javascript / jQuery there is an option to add more fields, like:

```js
$('a').click(function()
{
    $('form').append( $('input[type="text"]').clone() );
    return false;
});
```

It's just some dummy code, but to make clear that it's a dynamic form.

When this form is submitted and I go back (just with the back button in the browser), the extra added fields with the values are gone!

How to handle this easy?

**UPDATE**

I'm using CodeIgniter and the form validation. If the form fails all the variables will stay where they are and I've done some custom coding so the dynamic fields and there values are still there. Can I use some part of this for what I'm trying to do? Basically everything is already there for the form validation. Now this has to work with while going back to...

Comment: @rahulmaindargi, That question makes no sense here...

Comment: @epascarello why not.. the qustion appears to be therotic. if there OP has tried something to acheve and facing problem,.. it will be easier to help than just come with complete solution out of blue.

Comment: If you want the state of your application to be consistent when using the back/forward buttons in the browser. You will have to make a solution based on ajax and changing the url without reloading the page. Something like AngularJS could probably help you a long way here, if you don't want to write it all yourself.

Comment: @Roy that is perfectly normal because of the page life cycle on the client side. You need to find a way to persist this data of added fields on the server (session) and build the form back from zero. Ajax calls can help with this. Or in html5 make use of the localstorage to keep all client-sided.

Comment: Maybe there was a simple trick, that's why I didn't told what I've tried. Sadly there isn't so I've to do something with storing the information in a session and get that information with ajax. Or with localstorage.. Like store all fields in localstorage before submitting the form and after pressing the back button recreate all the added fields with there values.

Comment: If you submit form using ajax, you can try hashChange event.

Comment: Thanks, but the form isn't submitting through Ajax. Just updated my question to!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and trying a while I've used sessionStorage for this. Before the form submits all the values will be saved in it and when the user is clicking the back button everything is set back. For example before submit:

```
$('form').submit(function()
{
    var array           = {};
    array['name']       = [];
    array['counter']    = 0;

    $('input').each(function()
    {
        array['name'].push( $(this).val() );
        array['counter']++;
    });

    sessionStorage.setItem('input', JSON.stringify(array));
});
```

And on load:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('input'))
{
    var array = JSON.parse( sessionStorage.getItem('input') );

    for (var n = 0; n < (array['counter'] - 1); ++ n)
    {
        $('form').append( $('input[type="text"]').clone() );
    }

    $('input').each(function(index,value)
    {
        $(this).val( array['name'][index] );
    });

    sessionStorage.removeItem('input');
}
```

And I've written a blog post about this with an online demo: http://royduineveld.nl/blog/en/tips-trucs/449/waardes-behouden-na-verzenden-van-dynamisch-formulier/

Answer (score 0):

The submit button will make a new request for the document, unloading the current one. The easiest way to save your progress on the page is to not unload it at all. You can find a simple implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803095/without-closing-the-popup-window-how-to-submit-the-form-value-to-server)

You can also try using cookies or local storage to store the state of your document.

**Update**
I just realized you could also use

```
$("form").bind('submit',function(){
   return false;
});
```

However this will not solve your problem if you unload the document. And use the "back" button to re-load it. The only things that could save you then are cookies and local storage.

Comment: Handling the submit through Ajax isn't an option in my case.